# The inverse of a parametrization is differentiable.

Tags: differential-geometry

[image]

Hi. I'm thinking about a statement in the example above (do Carmo):

If $\mathbf{x}:U\subset\mathbb{R}^2\to S$ is a parametrization, $\mathbf{x}^{-1}:\mathbf{x}(U)\to\mathbb{R}^2$ is differentiable.

========

Being a parametrization, $\mathbf{x}$ is certainly differentiable and has an inverse $\mathbf{x}^{-1}$. Is this strong enough to guarantee that $\mathbf{x}^{-1}$ is differentiable? How could this happen? Thanks.

Comment: Do you know the inverse function theorem?

Comment: Yes. Maybe I should identify the definition of differentiability of $\mathbf{x}^{-1}$.